# How to get around a unique constraint violation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue where an autonomous transaction out of my reach will try to insert data into a table, but the data may already be existing. We need to find a solution to handle the unique integrity constraint without removing the constraint as another program depends on this constraint validation.

I've tried creating a before trigger that will delete the existing entry, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_BEFORE_INSERT_REPLACE_DC_DEVICE_TACTICAL_FIX_INV_LOADER
BEFORE INSERT
ON DC_DEVICE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    FAKE_DEVICE_STATUS VARCHAR2(3 BYTE);
BEGIN
    -- constraint exception occurs before this statement
    DELETE FROM DC_DEVICE WHERE DEVICE_ID_PK = :NEW.DEVICE_ID_PK;
END;
```

After that, I've thought of deleting the constraint and adding a trigger with a conditional statement, all entries from the broken program are different, so I can differentiate them. With that statement, if the device already exists and the insert does not come from the broken program, then fail to proceed, else delete the existing entry and proceed with the insertion.

The solution above seems like a working solution, but my question is, **is there any feature that would let me do the same in a more elegant way?**

Comment: This seems like a problem with he application inserting data, it should be using merge or handle unique constraint violation. Anyhow, an idea is to rename the table and put a view in front of it, you can then add instead of triggers that put violating rows in an exception table.

Comment: what do you want to do with the records you try to insert that are violating the constraint ? you want to keep them, you want to replace the existing ones ?

Comment: I want to replace the records, but I can't change the query the application makes, we have no control over the code, but we have to find a solution...

Comment: How would you differentiate the records?  Potentially, you want to use a function-based index to create a conditional unique constraint.

Comment: Well all the broken entries have a device status of 'FKE', not the other ones

Comment: i think if you cant change the actual software , you can use triggers. but its the best to ask the software creators to fix this issue

Comment: The problem with the software is the release process, it takes 2 months before anything touches production, so we need to find a SQL solution meanwhile. I've added a composite primary key, and that seems to be permission to avoid the unique constraint, I just need to add a trigger validation

Comment: So if device status != 'FKE' then device_id should be unique?  If so, you can implement that with the function-based index.

Comment: That which is trying to insert into your table is not a `pragma` but an `autonomous transaction`. `pragma` means "compiler directive" and it doesn't actually have much to do with the database part of Oracle.

Comment: As a general principle, if something is wrong and it is "out of your control", you should insist that the problem should be corrected by whoever does have control over the wrong thing. Working around it will in the future lead to even bigger problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use `instead of` trigger. However, this solution requires for you to rename your tables and create views with the names they had. That way you don't affect the application logic, however it could affect the overall performance, so it should be tested properly.

Nevertheless, using triggers to change wrong application logic is not a very good idea. I understand your predicament that sometimes we need to find workarounds to existing problems, but that does not make it right.

Anyway, below a simple example that you can apply to your logic

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number primary key , c2 varchar2(1) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t rename to tbl_t ;

Table altered.

SQL>  create view t as ( select c1 , c2 from tbl_t ) ;

View created.
```

Now we create a `instead of` trigger

```
SQL> create or replace trigger tr_v_t
  2  instead of insert
  3  on t
  4  for each row
  5  declare
  6    pk_violation_exception exception;
  7    pragma exception_init(pk_violation_exception, -00001);
  8  begin
  9    insert into tbl_t (c1,c2)
 10    values ( :new.c1,:new.c2 );
 11    exception
 12      when pk_violation_exception then
 13        dbms_output.put_line('ora-00001 (pk_violation_exception) captured');
 14        update tbl_t
 15        set c2   = :new.c2
 16        where c1 = :new.c1 ;
 17* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.
```

With this trigger, any attempt to violate the constraint will make the update of the value possible in the final table.

```
SQL> select * from t ;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into t values ( 1 , 'A' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into t values ( 2, 'B' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into t values ( 2, 'C' ) ;
ORA-00001 (pk_violation_exception) captured

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tbl_t ;

        C1 C
---------- -
         1 A
         2 C
```

Comment: I agree a 100% with your statement, but there's little I can do, thanks for the answer, I'll try that and make it the official answer once it works

Comment: That doesn't exactly work in my case, but it's a really good alternative, thanks!